# How can I have individual logos shown in the Sites I'm Following

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, mysites, following, site-logo

I've been asked if it was possible to replace the default "SharePoint" logo with a unique logo for each site that I am following?  We are using SharePoint 2016 On-Prem.  Can this be accomplished?

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can set logo for each Site in **Site Settings > Title, Describtion and Logo** > Change logo here (you ca upload from computer here or find on SharePoint )

Comment: You're welcome :) vote up please :)